# Child resembling father or mother (Hadith clarification)

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

> And if a man's discharge proceeded that of the woman, then the child
> resembles the father, and if the woman's discharge proceeded that of
> the man, then the child resembles the mother."

Okay, isn't the above hadith totally unscientific?
Because we know that resemblance is actually implemented by DNAs and genes, not due to the fact who has orgasm first.

Answer (score 1):

The actual wordings in Arabic is

> وَإِذَا سَبَقَ مَاءُ الرَّجُلِ مَاءَ الْمَرْأَةِ نَزَعَ الْوَلَدَ،
>   وَإِذَا سَبَقَ مَاءُ الْمَرْأَةِ نَزَعَتْ

translation given in sunnah.com is

> And if a man's discharge proceeded that of the woman, then the child
>   resembles the father, and if the woman's discharge proceeded that of
>   the man, then the child resembles the mother." https://sunnah.com/urn/41620

The word used for "proceeded" in Arabic is sabaq (سبق). It can also mean priority or precedence. Actually there is no mention of orgasm as mentioned in your question.

[image]

Hans Wehr

We know if genes in father's sperm takes precedence over genes in mother's ovum than the child resembles father and vice versa. So there is nothing wrong in this hadith from a scientific view.

Comment: but man, the discharge of women has no role in determining anything. It's just there for the lubricant.

Comment: Oh sorry, *lubricration

Comment: in hadith it uses "ma'ul mar'a" which mean literally "fluid of woman". nothing to indicate that it is something discharged outside. Due to limited knowledge in the past earlier scholars may have interpreted it as discharge.

Comment: I'm still not following because no fluid of woman has anything to do with genes or the resemblance of the child. It is only the genes contained within the egg (not a fluid) and sperm. I'm also not sure what you mean by "genes in father's sperm takes precedence over genes in mother's ovum"? Can you explain what you mean here? Referencing a description of genetics, heredity, and parent-child resemblance may be helpful here.

Comment: @AlexStrasser . Just to point out, all genes in cells are in solution so it is technically a fluid.

Comment: @AlexStrasser Just like sperm is part of semen which is collection of fluid, ovum that is released from ovary is part of fluid that transport it to the uterus. The genes that child inherit is a mixture of genes from father and mother and features that child expresses depends on which genes get more precedence over other.

Comment: @AbuZiyad What do you mean by genes having "precedence?"

Comment: @TheZ what do you mean genes are "in solution?" Genes are on chromosomes that are protected from the cytoplasm by being encased in the nuclear membrane. See [cell nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_nucleus). Can you explain further?